# Iterating over C++ variadic template typelist

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Suppose I use a variadic template as typelist:

```
template <typename ... Types> struct tl {};
using my_list = tl<MyTypeA, MyTypeB, MyTypeC>;
```

Now I want to invoke a template function for each type, such as:

```
myFunc<MyTypeA>();
myFunc<MyTypeB>();
```

How would I accomplish that ?

Answer (score 1):

With C++17, you might use fold expression

```
template <typename ...Ts>
void call_my_func(my_list<Ts...> )
{
    (myFunc<Ts>(), ...);
}
```

Comment: Heh, our answers were so similar that I accidentally edited yours.

Answer (score 1):

With c++17 you can use [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold).

```
template <typename ... Types>
void callMyFunc(my_list<Types...>) {
    (myFunc<Types>(), ...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C++11 version:

```cpp
template <typename ... Types>
void forEachMyFunc(tl<Types...>)
{
    int dummy[] = {
        (myFunc<Types>(), 0)...
    };
    (void)dummy;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4nK67M

Here is [more devious version](https://godbolt.org/z/8d7h4s):

```cpp
template<typename T>
class MyFunc {
public:
    void operator()() const {
        myFunc<T>();
    }
};

template <template<typename> class F, typename ... Types>
void forEachTypeDo(tl<Types...>)
{
    int dummy[] {
        (F<Types>{}(), 0)...
    };
    (void)dummy;
}
...
forEachTypeDo<MyFunc>(my_list{});
```