# How to wrap C++ types into a list for variadic arguments

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-functions

[Related to an earlier question from me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65215959/iterating-over-c-variadic-template-typelist)

Just starting to use fold expressions, but it does not yet behave as I intend to.
The background is that I want to be able to define 'my_list' in a dedicated header file to simplify maintenance. A call with  separate types works, but when calling with 'my_list' it does not work.
See comment in the example.

Is there a way to get the 2nd calling type working ?

```cpp
template < typename ... Types > struct tl
{
};
using my_list = tl <int, float, uint64_t>;


    template <typename ... Types>
void myFunc2() 
{
    (std::cout << "Size: " << sizeof (Types) << std::endl, ...);     
} 

main () 
{
    myFunc2<int,uint64_t,bool,uint16_t>();  // This call prints size of each type
    myFunc2<my_list>();                     // This call only prints 1
}
```

Comment: Please add the c++ tag to all C++ questions so that more users will see the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specialize on your typelist (or perhaps any typelist). Using function object variable templates, this would be:

```
template <typename ... Types>
static constexpr auto myFunc2 = [] {
    (std::cout << "Size: " << sizeof (Types) << std::endl, ...);     
};

template <template<class...> class TL, typename ... Types>
static constexpr auto myFunc2<TL<Types...>> = [] {
    (std::cout << "Size: " << sizeof (Types) << std::endl, ...);     
};
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/vqrWbG).

Comment: This basically does what I want. There is only one thing I do not understand yet. If I only have the 2nd function from your example and only use the call 'myFunc2<my_list>()'  it results in a compile error.

Comment: Pattern matching on something inside angle brackets `<>` needs to use partial specialization, which means there must be a primary template of the same kind. Here we're using variable templates so there must be a primary variable template; you could also do this with class templates in which case you'd need a primary class template (which could be incomplete), but then you'd also need `myFunc2` to be a function template or variable template forwarding to the class template.